# MongoDB C++ Query a child element of a document

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-cxx-driver

I am struggling for days with the C++ Driver of MongoDB...

I want to give out every child element of a specific document. Example:

```
Structure JSON-Document:
{
    docID : "123" 
    parts  : 
    {
        part : "a"
        part : "b"
        part : "c"
    }
}

bsoncxx::stdx::optional<bsoncxx::document::value> resultDocument =
            collection.find_one(document{} << "docID" << "123" << finalize);

bsoncxx::document::view viewDocumentResult = resultDocument.value();
```

Now i want to have a list of all parts. As example output:

```
a

b

c
```

I am only able to give out all top-elements as docID and parts, but not the child-elements of parts :-(

```
auto num_keys = 

std::distance(begin(viewDocumentResult), end(viewDocumentResult));
    std::cout << "document has " << num_keys << " keys." << std::endl;
```

Output: document has 2 keys.

```
std::vector<std::string> doc_keys;

std::transform(begin(viewDocumentResult), end(viewDocumentResult), std::back_inserter(doc_keys), [](bsoncxx::document::element ele) {
    // note that key() returns a string_view
    return ele.key().to_string();
});

std::cout << "document keys are: " << std::endl;
for (auto key : doc_keys) {
    std::cout << key << " " << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
docID

parts
```

But how can I output the child elements of parts?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have here, the output is expected and correct. You have asked to accumulate all of the keys of the top level fields of `viewDocumentResult` into `doc_keys` and then you print them out. And the top level fields in the indicated document are `docId` and `parts`.

If you want the keynames of the subfields of `parts`, get a view of that document and iterate over that instead:

```
auto viewDocumentResultParts = viewDocumentResult['parts'].get_document().view();

std::vector<std::string> doc_keys;

std::transform(begin(viewDocumentResultParts), end(viewDocumentResultParts), std::back_inserter(doc_keys), [](bsoncxx::document::element ele) {
    // note that key() returns a string_view
    return ele.key().to_string();
});

std::cout << "document keys are: " << std::endl;
for (auto key : doc_keys) {
    std::cout << key << " " << std::endl;
}
```